# Mathematical expectation and variance of the dice game

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, dice

On the table there are N regular six-faced cubes. John calls a number from 1 to 6, rolls the dice,and takes all the dice that have this number. Then Petr repeats this operation. This procedure continues until all the cubes are disassembled. Find the average and variance of the number of cubes that will get John

I don't have any ideas. How is it possible to divide this random variable into more convenient and simple ones? I would like at least some hint I do not know how to approach the problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What on earth is a hexagon cube?

Comment: its six faces cube

Comment: Please post your efforts and ideas.

Comment: I don't have any ideas. How is it possible to divide this random variable into more convenient and simple ones? I would like at least some hint I do not know how to approach the problem

Comment: When you're starting out with an area of math, sometimes you just face a blank wall and have no idea how to enter into the problem--even though a teacher or book has given you all of the tools needed to solve it.  So here are suggestions that might seem obvious in retrospect.  Keep in mind this: Simple probability calculations can be understood solely in terms of addition of mutually exclusive outcomes, and multiplications of probabilities (sometimes conditional probabilities).

Comment: (btw there's a typo at present: what comes after "get John"?)  First question for you:  What is the probability of each outcome on a single toss?  Second question: What is the probability of John's or Petr's chosen outcome coming up on a single toss?  Third question: Are the different tosses independent?  What does your answer imply about multiplying probabilities?  I would ask more questions to help lead you into the problem, but I don't know what comes after "get John"--I don't know what the full problem is.  However, the answer will involve multiplying numbers on die faces by probabilities.

Comment: "addition of mutually exclusive outcomes" in my first comment should be "addition of probabilities of mutually exclusive outcomes".

Comment: A hexagon, by definition, is a two-dimensional shape (polygon) with six corners.  The term does not apply to 3 dimensional objects and, if it did, it would not apply to cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to "divide" the random variable into easier-to-manage variables.

Imagine that we are able to label each die in a way that does not affect the outcome of the roll, but allows us to identify the first die, the second die, the third die, and so forth all the way up to the $N$th die.
For each integer $k$ from $1$ to $N$, you can ask whether John has the $k$th die at the end of the game.
Let $X_k = 1$ if John gets the $k$th die, but $X_k = 0$ if Petr gets the $k$th die.

Then the number of dice that John has at the end is a random variable $Y$ defined by
$$ Y = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + \cdots + X_N. $$

A good thing about $X_k$ is it is a Bernoulli variable, so if you can just figure out the probability that John gets the $k$th die, you know all you need to know about $X_k$ (its expectation and variance).

There are a number of other difficult-looking problems for which this kind of decomposition is useful.

As for the probability that John gets the $k$th die, just consider that the die will be rolled repeatedly until either it rolls a number that John calls out or it rolls a number that Petr calls out.
The probability for that particular die to end up in John's possession (or Petr's) on a particular roll is simply a matter of whether it is still on the table and whether it shows the same number John (or Petr) called out. That is not affected by how many other dice were already won by John or Petr or how many other dice are still on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Avg no of cubes $\varepsilon(avg)=\frac{N}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2} N+\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{4} N--$

$\varepsilon\left(avg\right)=\frac{6 N}{11}$

Variance by symmary = var (cubes John get) = var ( cubes Petr get ) $=$ var $(\text { any } \text { number })$

$\operatorname{var}\left(Joh n\right)=\operatorname{var}(\text { Normal } 6 \operatorname{side}  \operatorname{cube})$

$=\frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^{6}\left(i-3 \cdot 5^{2}\right)$

$\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{John})=2.5$

Comment: What is the point of reposting [this answer of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3766268/446262)?